# Converting from a text field to an numeric in Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, floating-point

If I have an EditText component on my screen that I have specified `inputType="decimal"` for (i.e. a numeric/decimal field), what is the best way to convert it to an decimal value in the application code?

[image: Numeric EditText]

[Google recommends](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#avoidfloat) avoiding `float`s, and avoiding creating objects unnecessarily (and I assume any auto-unboxing code is bad too), so I take these as my constraints. I realise a small application probably doesn't need to worry too much, but I haven't been able to find a 'best-practice' solution to this.

The most common solution appears to be this:

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(txtInput);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the best solution, you should also check for "NumberFormatException" exceptions, just incase of non valid charecters. Then return feedback to the user if it's wrong.

If you don't want floats, your going to have to look at fixed point arthimetic. The reason they want you to avoid using float is because it's rarely implemented on phone cpu's(Probbly arm), and has to be implemented in software which is slow. Fixed point is usally surported in hardware.

Comment: Cool, google do specify that the float operations are likely to be software rather than hardware because of the mobile cpu, and thus slower.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons that using `Double.parseDouble` is the best solution:

- On a normal CPU, `float` operations are implemented by hardware operations. This is most likely *not* built into a mobile CPU, and would be replaced by software operations (which are significantly slower).
- Using static methods of `Double`, rather than creating an instance via `new Double(txtInput)` is better for memory usage as it means only the class definition is loaded into the JVM, and we never have additional overhead from state information created by an instance of `Double`.
- An alternative to `Double.parseDouble` is `Double.valueOf`, but this returns an instance of `Double`, and then we have created an object unnecessarily since we are just unboxing it to a `double` primitive.